# Push Failed - IntelliJ

Tags: github, intellij-idea

I am trying to push any commits from IntelliJ but keep getting this error message:

"Push failed Cannot spawn C:\Users\laure\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2020.1\tmp\intellij-git-askpass.sh: No such file or directory could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory"

I can do it from terminal but not from the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like antivirus is blocking execution of the script, which is needed to authenticate into the remote via IDE.

Please try disabling antivirus or add C:\Users\laure\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2020.1\tmp\intellij-git-askpass.sh

It might be a result of AV, or group policy blocking java scripts.

Also please check whether the file intellij-git-askpass.sh exists.

Comment: I have the same problem on Mac OS M1. And there is no antivirus on Mac OS

Answer (score 0):

I checked AV. Bitdefender tends to be paranoid, but i checked the notifications on it and I can se that it is not blocking the push.

I am new to IntelliJ, might I ask what you mean by adding:

C:\Users\laure\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2020.1\tmp\intellij-git-askpass.sh.

Also I could not find the file:

intellij-git-askpass.sh

PS
Thank you for taking your time to answer.

Comment: If this is a part of the question, please add this text to the question via edit button and remove this "answer"